# How to resume a file upload when user aborts and returns

Tags: php, forms, http, file-upload

I was wondering a few things about file uploads in PHP and how to best handle certain aspects of this technique. I've made a little script based on W3Schools example to better illustrate the purpose of this question.

#### What if a user closes the browser while uploading a file?

Well, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the file will still be in your /tmp/ directory and will not be removed until the /tmp/ directory is cleaned up.

#### So if I would like to resume an upload, what then?

And this was the question I was not able to answer. That's why I've posted my question here. So in short: How can I resume a user's upload when he returns after closiing the browser or leaving the page?

#### My form

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
     Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

#### My PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $target = "upload/"; 
     $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
     if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        die ("There was a problem while uploading your file");
     }
     header("Location: index.php");
     exit;
}
```

#### The actual question

A user takes the following steps:

- User selects a file
- User uploads the form
- User closes browser

Now I want the following to happen:

- User returns
- User selects same file
- User submits form
- Upload resumes at the point it stopped last time

What i would like to know is if this is possible and how i can achieve this.

Comment: you will never know if it's the same file. it could have been changed in the meantime.

Comment: you could do some fancy stuff by transmitting byte per byte via js and check the file via hash. But that is going to be absurd. Best you let them upload it all over again

Answer (score 5):

Another good way to do this would be to use [tus protocol](https://tus.io) since [vimeo has also adopted it](https://medium.com/vimeo-engineering-blog/vimeo-is-adopting-tus-d5e999acd517) recently. tus is a HTTP based protocol for resumable file uploads so you can carry on where you left off without re-uploading whole data again in case of any interruptions. You can find various implementations of the protocol in different languages [here](https://tus.io/implementations.html). For php, you can use [this package](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/tus-php).

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution that might help me and other in the future. It's called Resumable.js

> #### What is Resumable.js
>
> It’s a JavaScript library providing multiple simultaneous, stable and resumable uploads via the HTML5 File API.
>
> Resumable.js does not have any external dependencies other than the HTML5 File API. This is relied on for the ability to chunk files into smaller pieces. Currently, this means that support is widely available in to Firefox 4+, Chrome 11+, Safari 6+ and Internet Explorer 10+.

Samples and examples are available in the [GitHub](https://github.com/23/resumable.js).repository

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this package](https://github.com/khanzadimahdi/UploadManager)

take a look at examples/js-examples/resumable-chunk-upload in the package's examples